# BLE Android write characteristic data

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a BLE project using Android. I want to write characteristic data and send it to a BLE chip.

[image: Android Screenshot]

*I want to rewrite ISEN_Toulon*

I used this code to write characteristic data, but data `"ISEN_Toulon"` isn't replaced by `"TEST"` as expected.

```
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic;

private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner =
        new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition, long id)
            {
                if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
                    final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = mGattCharacteristics.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                    final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
.....
                    // READ
                    if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                        // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                        // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                        if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                    mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                            mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                        }
                        mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                        Log.d("myTag", "1");
                    }
                    // NOTIFY
                    if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                        mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                characteristic, true);
                        Log.d("myTag", "2");
                    }

                    // WRITE  
                    characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE);
                    characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
                    characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE);

                    mWriteCharacteristic = characteristic;

                    String str = "TEST";
                    byte[] strBytes = str.getBytes();
                    characteristic.setValue(strBytes);
                    writeCharacteristic(characteristic)

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
};
```

Comment: Why does the code not work? Explain.

Comment: Where do you read the value back in?  Is that in your adapter code?  if so, please post.

Comment: @rothloup  I edited my post and I added the `READ` part of the code.

Comment: @Johnrednex well, you appear to read before your write, so that might be your issue.  In any case, I think you need to do a better job of explaining exactly what the problem is.  What piece of code isn't working?  no one is going to pick apart your code - you need to remove everything that is irrelevant and keep all relevant context.  Show your expected result, and your actual result, and related code.  nothing more, nothing less.  [See more here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can find an implementation for the write method in this project: https://github.com/Fakher-Hakim/android-BluetoothLeGatt

Comment: Thank you but the issue was solved long time ago. It was the ble chip authorizations not set properly.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but as I had a similar issue today, others might like an answer.

The issue it that you set the WriteType 3 times - effectually overwriting the two first values set.
Your code:

```
...
characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE);
characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE);
```

Two issues:

- The values starting with `PROPERTY_` are not write types, hence only `WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE` is valid
- The third call to `setWriteType()` overwrites the valid value with an invalid value, and the Android stack then ignores your write request.

Unless there is a specific reason to use `WRITE_NO_RESPONSE`, you should use a normal write (`WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT`). The Android stack sometimes miss a write - as in the application do call write for example 5 times, but only 1 or 2 of the writes are send over air. This is even when the `onCharacteristicWrite()` callback reports success.

```
characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem with you. The detail way to solve the problem I do not remember. But I have a code to write BLE characteristics to BLE devices like this:(at least it works for me)

```
    public OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
            if(charas.size()>=6){
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                        charas.get(0);
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic_write = charas.get(5);
                int charaProp_write = characteristic_write.getProperties();
                int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
                //String getUUID = characteristic.getUuid().toString();
                if (((charaProp_write | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0)
                        &&  
                        (characteristic_write != null)){

                    if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                        mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                    }   
                    byte[] writev = new byte[SIMPLEPROFILE_CHAR6_LEN];
                    Arrays.fill(writev, (byte)'0');
                    byte[] getedit1 = edit1.getText().toString().getBytes();//edit1.getText().toString().getBytes();
                    byte[] getedit2 = edit2.getText().toString().getBytes();
                    byte[] getedit3 = edit3.getText().toString().getBytes();


                    //System.out.println(getedit1 + " " + getedit2 + " " + getedit3);

                    if ((getedit1.length + getedit2.length + getedit3.length) <= (max_syvlength+max_spvlength+max_tuvlength)) {
                        //this 'if' can be canceled
                        writev[0] = (byte)'1';
                        writev[1] = (byte)(getedit1.length);
                        writev[2] = (byte)(getedit2.length);
                        writev[3] = (byte)(getedit3.length);
                        System.arraycopy(getedit1, 0, writev, 4, getedit1.length);
                        System.arraycopy(getedit2, 0, writev, 4 + getedit1.length, getedit2.length);
                        System.arraycopy(getedit3, 0, writev, 4 + getedit1.length + getedit2.length, getedit3.length);
                        writev[4 + getedit1.length + getedit2.length + getedit3.length] = '@';
                    }

                    /*
                    for(int i = 0;i<15;i++){
                        Log.d(TAG, "is:" + writev[i]);
                    }
                    */                      

                    characteristic_write.setValue(writev);
                    characteristic_write.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
                    mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic_write);

                }
                if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                    // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                    // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                    if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                        mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                    }
                    mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);

                }       
                if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                    mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                            characteristic, true);
                }

            }
        }

        GotoMyActivity();

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your case is of writing multiple bytes of data to the characteristic to bluetooth device, which has few rules:

1. Android can not write parallel data packets to the ble device.
2. The data should not exceed 20 bytes
3. You should divide the data to chunks and send to ble device
4. You should wait for the **write callback onCharacteristicWrite()** before sending next data packet to be written to the ble device.

Comment: "The data should not exceed 20 bytes" should be "The data should not exceed 20 bytes unless the MTU has been increased, or the remote device supports Long Writes".

Answer (score 0):

Trying to override callback function in

```
BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback(){
//something callback function like:

@Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
      //do something read/write
}
```

You need to figure out how BLE callback function work!!!
Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback) out.

Because BLE write/read can only be done in one time. It's mean that if I read a data from characteristic. I can only do another write/read action after previous one done.